# Consider the sequence {$a_n$}, for $a_n= \sin\left(\frac{(4n-1)\pi}{6}\right)$. Find all of its limit points, $\limsup\;$ and $\;\liminf.$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Consider the sequence $\{a_n\}$, for $a_n= \sin \left(\frac{(4n-1)\pi}{6}\right)$. Find all of its limit points, lim sup, and lim inf.

So for this problem I know that to find the limit points I have to show that there exists a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\} = N$ but I'm not quite sure how to go about that and for the lim sup and lim inf I have to find some $M'$ but not quite sure on the set up.

Comment: How many values can $a_n$ take on?

Comment: i dont think its bounded by any interval

Comment: Even though $\sin x \in [-1,1]$ for all $x$?

Answer (score 1):

Let's note that $\sin(x)=\sin(2\pi k+x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}, k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Also, for $n=3k$, we can see that $\frac{4n}{6}=\frac{12k}{6}=2\pi$. So we'll look at subseries in the form $a_{3k}, a_{3k+1}, a_{3k+2}$, which cover the series $a_n$ since $3k, 3k+1, 3k+2$ cover $\mathbb{N}$.

Let's look at the following subseries:

$a_{3k}=\sin(\frac{(4(3k)-1)\pi}{6})=\sin(2\pi-\frac{\pi}{6})=\sin(-\pi/6)=-\frac{1}{2}$

$a_{3k+1}=\sin(\frac{(4(3k+1)-1)\pi}{6})=\sin(2\pi+\frac{3\pi}{6})=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})=1$

$a_{3k+2}=\sin(\frac{(4(3k+2)-1)\pi}{6})=\sin(2\pi+\frac{7\pi}{6})=sin(\frac{7\pi}{6})=-\frac{1}{2}$